# Inputs value is the same as others input when using array.push()

Tags: reactjs, native, reminders

I have a problem where the value of my inputs are all the same when I am using array.push(). So basically, the input time and select dropdown below will render based on the dropdown above (how many times a day). If the user select 2, the input time and select dropdown below will render to 2 times. After that, when I want to input the time and select dropdown, the value will be the same for all the input. The sample interface will be shown in the picture below. So do you guys have any idea on how to solve this?

```
import React from 'react'
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
import { StyleSheet, View, Platform } from "react-native";
import {
  Select,
  SelectItem,
  IndexPath,
  Button
} from "@ui-kitten/components";
import { useState } from "react";

const to12Hours = require("to12hours");

const cap = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

export default function Reminder(displayHowt) {

  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("date");
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [time, setTime] = useState("00.00");
  const [selectedCap, setSelectedCap] = React.useState(new IndexPath(0));


  const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    setShow(Platform.OS === "ios");
    setDate(currentDate);

    let tempDate = new Date(currentDate);

    setTime(to12Hours(tempDate.toTimeString().slice(0, 5)));
  };
  const showMode = (currentMode) => {
    setShow(true);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };
  const showTimepicker = () => {
    showMode("time");
  };
  const displayCap = cap[selectedCap.row];
  const renderOption = (title) => <SelectItem title={title} />;

  let x = new Array(displayHowt.displayHowt);
  console.log(x)
  console.log(displayHowt.displayHowt);

    let items=[];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < displayHowt.displayHowt; i++) {
      items.push(<View key={i} style={styles.row}> 
        <Button appearance='ghost' status='primary'  onPress={showTimepicker} >{time}</Button>
        {show && (
          <DateTimePicker
          name={`input-${i}`}
            testID="TimePicker"
            value={date}
            mode={mode}
            is24Hour={false}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        )}
        <Select
        name={`select-${i}`}
            label="Capsule"
            style={styles.howt}
            placeholder="Default"
            value={displayCap}
            selectedIndex={selectedCap}
            onSelect={(index) => setSelectedCap(index)}
          >
            {cap.map(renderOption)}
          </Select>
      </View>);
    }

 
  return (<View>
    {items}
  </View>
  )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    margin: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignContent: "space-between",
  },
  howt: {
    width: 150,
    marginBottom: 10,
    color: "black",
  },
});
```

[image: Sample ouput]

Comment: As it's currently worded it isn't actually clear if you technically have a question. This reads more like "I'm trying to conditionally render UI, I don't know how to do it, please show me.". I would suggest breaking down your code into more digestible chunks or perhaps consider rewording.

Comment: I know how to render it but I'm just stuck where the input is all the same. I have tried to 
 so many possible things solve it but I couldn't.

Comment: Try printing out your component state/props either in the HTML or in the console. That will tell you what your source of truth is doing.